# How do I set up smtp on Vista so I can use System.Net.Mail from local picup directory?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I've tried using the below solution (also found here: [How do I set up smtp on Vista so I can use System.Net.Mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701887/how-do-i-set-up-smtp-on-vista-so-i-can-use-system-net-mail/701926#701926)) but I receive "Cannot get IIS pickup directory". I know I am pointing to an existing directory and my web.config are set up correctly, are there permissions I need to set up on the directory before I can write to it?

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
            <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
                    <specifiedPickupDirectory
                      pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\maildrop"/>
            </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the file permissions on the `maildrop` folder?  You can enable write for all users and see if that works.  If you just want IIS to write to it, I think the user is ASPNET, but I might be wrong on that.

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929/hidden-features-of-asp-net/75170#75170) seems to show a "\" at the end of the directory path (I would hope asp.net would understand that though)